# loop to add multiple popups problem - flex

Tags: apache-flex, function, for-loop, popup

I have a for loop that I'm trying to display multiple popups with.

I seem to have multiple popups appearing on the screen, but after I'm done and close the top popup all the buttons on the others below it seem to stop functioning.

How can I make all the popups retain their functionality after the one before is closed?

Here's the code that I'm using to add the popups:

```
reminderadd = reminder_add(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,reminder_add,true));
reminderadd.postpone_button.visible = true;
reminderadd.title.text = "Reminder - " + remindernum;
reminderadd["add_button"].addEventListener("click",reminderUpdate);
reminderadd["cancel_button"].addEventListener("click",reminderDismiss);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(reminderadd);
```

Comment: One popup is already not very good UX. Are you trying to chase people away from your app with multiple? Anyway, you don't show enough code in the question to identify the source of the problem.

Comment: What is your code for removing the event listeners?  You're probably removing the listeners from the second item down in the stack, rather than the top item.  Since you can't close that one, it "looks" like none of the functionality is working on any of the popups.  But since I don't think you're retaining references to all of the popups, unless you're using event.currentTarget to remove the listeners, it's really unlikely you're removing listeners from more than one of the popups.  Your symptoms suggest it's a different one than the one you closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the 3rd parameter to false in createPopUp()

@RIAstar - When I wake up on the morning, I have two alarms set 5 minutes apart. If the first alarm showed an amalgamated alert list, I wouldn't have come into work on time =P

Also add useWeakReference as per Amy's suggestion:

reminderadd["add_button"].addEventListener("click",reminderUpdate, false, 0, true);
reminderadd["cancel_button"].addEventListener("click",reminderDismiss, false, 0, true);